# How to update data from database with api call in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a api call who give me the list of data, and I am iterating data via ng-repeat (its a list of more than 100 items)

For getting list of data I have call an Api in App Controller in angularjs like this:

```
 var path = serverUrl + 'api/getAllMails';
    $http.get(path).then(function (result) {
      $scope.mails=result
    })
```

For Iterating the mails in Html file i have use table like the below

```
<table>
    <tr class="header">
        <th class="center">Id</th>
        <th class="center">Mode of Payment</th>
        <th class="center">Payment Collected</th>
        <th class="center">Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="mail in mails">
        <td>{{mail.id}}</td>
        <td>{{mail.paymentType}}</td>
        <td>Rs. {{mail.cost}}
            <input type="text" ng-model="mail.cost">
            <button ng-click="updateCost=(mail.id, mail.cost)">Update Cost</button>
        </td>
        <td>{{mail.status}}
            <input type="text" ng-model="mail.status">
            <button ng-click="updateStatus(mail.id, mail.status)">Update Status</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Suppose in the first iterations the cost will be "100" and the status will be "pending". And I have to update this row only, change cost to "1000" and status will be "Delivered".

In my App controller of Angularjs I have create methods. These two methods are calling apis and updating data in database and return the list of updated mails.

```
$scope.updateStatus = function(mailId, mailStatus) {
    var path = serverUrl + 'api/updateStatus';
    $http.get(path, {
        params: {
            mailId: mailId,
            mailStatus: mailStatus
        }
    }).then(function(result) {
        $scope.mails = result
    })
}

$scope.updateCost = function(mailId, mailCost) {
    var path = serverUrl + 'api/updateStatus';
    $http.get(path, {
        params: {
            mailId: mailId,
            mailCost: mailCost
        }
    }).then(function(result) {
        $scope.mails = result
    })
}
```

These code are working fine but while it took lot of time to load a page. So what can I do to reduce the loading time or is there any better way to do the same thing.

Any help will be appreciable. Thank you

Comment: What is taking long? The API call (pending) or the ng-repeat?

Comment: add an `track by $index`  or `track by mailId ` on your ng-repeat, probably not a huge difference, but it will help.

Comment: Guess the api call is taking a long time. Max you can do from front end part is that you can make the call on some button click or something or add a loader. So that the user experience will be much better.

Comment: Api call take 4,5 second, but ng-repeat took  more time.

Comment: I don't know the layout of the rest of your app, but you could also try to disable two-way-observed status on some parts of it, it could help.

Comment: You can follow the instructions in the link given below for optimizing ng-repeat
http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/

Comment: So your api is returning the complete collection from your database after every update? Could you not just return the updated row and replace the relevant object in your front-end model with the updated one?

Comment: Hi @MattHerbstritt , I am trying to update that single row from the database , but how can i replace that particular row in the the existing list. If you any idea to do the same then please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the entire dataset when there is no reason for that, you should only update the row you change. Ensure your `updateStatus` return the object you update and update that item in `$scope.mails`

In example

```
$scope.updateCost = function(mailId, mailCost) {
    var path = serverUrl + 'api/updateStatus';
    $http.get(path, {
        params: {
            mailId: mailId,
            mailStatus: mailCost
        }
    }).then(function(result) {
        // result is the item you changed
        for (var i = $scope.mails.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if($scope.mails[i].id === mailId) {
                $scope.mails[i] = result;
                return;
            }
        };
    })
}
```

Comment: Is it just me, or would it be much better if this was done using services and the data loaded on the appconfig?

Comment: Hi @Eric I am using the same as you defined the above but its not updating the row. Can you please explain it more or is there are any examples like this. Thanks

Comment: The problem is solved now I followed @Eric Herlitz's answer, Instead of load all the list again and again,  I just update the selected row, like Eric done in above answer.  Thank you so much all of you , I really appreciate you efforts.

Comment: @Naren-Mehta Great, than please accept this as the answer